How to get access token and id token for google oauth?
I am using Blazor Webassembly standalone + Asp.Net Web Api(.Net8.0). I want to implement Google Authentiaction. I successfully got the authorization code but having a problemgetting the access token and id token.I am referring to Google OpenId Connect.
I have used this code...
var authCode = "4/0AanRRrsWBIJ~~~~~~~~~~~~";
var clientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Google:ClientId") ?? string.Empty;
var clientSecret = configuration.GetValue<string>　　("Authentication:Google:ClientSecret") ?? string.Empty;
var redirectUri = "https://localhost:7210/authentication/login-callback";
var tokenUri = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "code", authCode },
    { "client_id", clientId },
    { "client_secret", clientSecret },
    { "redirect_uri", redirectUri },
    { "grant_type", "authorization_code" }
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenUri, content);

But, I got the error;
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'
Thank you in advance for any help.

what scopes are you requesting?

Thank you for the comment. I`m requesting "openid" and "profile".

Rather then edit your question with its resolution, it's good practice to add an answer to your own question. It's reasonable to also mark your own answer as the answer.

Thank you for your advice. I added an answer to my question.

[Resolved]
I wasn't thinking about PKCE.
I made changes to the following code, and it worked successfully.
var clientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Google:ClientId") ?? string.Empty;
var clientSecret = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:Google:ClientSecret") ?? string.Empty;
var redirectUri = "https://localhost:7210/authentication/login-callback";
var authCode = request.AuthCode;
var codeVerifer = request.CodeVerifer;
var tokenUri = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";

var body = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new("code", authCode),
    new("client_id", clientId),
    new("client_secret", clientSecret),
    new("redirect_uri", redirectUri),
    new("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
    **new("code_verifier",  codeVerifer),**
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(body);
var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

**httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));**

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenUri, content);

var result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ExchangedTokenResponse>();

